# Функция scroll на попуп окно не действует

Tags: jquery, прокрутка

Здравствуйте,сразу извиняюсь за глупый вопрос, но реально уже долго не могу дать условие на скролл на попуп окне. Во общем, открывается попуп, пытаюсь дать условие на скролл:

```
$('#popup_blok').scroll(function(){
  alert('ok');
});
```

но не действует, пробовал так:

```
$('#popup_block').live('scroll', function(){
  alert('ok');
});
```

тоже не действует, вообще 0 реакций.

popup_block блок загружается из БД через аякс. fade блок создается при клике и добавляется в dom элемент после wrapper:

```
<div id="wrapper"></div>
<div id="fade">
    <div id="left"></div>
    <div id="right"></div>
    <div id="popup_block">
        <div id="popup_conteiner">
            <!-- Загруженные элементы из БД -->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Выборку пробовал по разному: $('#popup_block'),$('#fade #popup_block'), $('#popup_conteiner') и т.д. Можно как нибудь дать условие на попуп окне на скролл?

Все дело в том что мне нужно узнать высоту #popup_conteiner, и его высоту присвоить #left и #right. Пробовал сразу присвоить в аяксе

```
success: function(html){ 
////////////////////
$('#right, #left').height($('#popup_conteiner').outerHeight(true));
});
```

Так дает не точную высоту,но если закрыть попук окно и снова открыть то точную высоту дает, а мне нужно сразу точную высоту. 
Пробовал и height() тоже результат не тот.

И теперь решил пробовать дать условие при скроллинге присвоить

```
$('#popup_block').live('scroll', function(){
$('#right, #left').height($('#popup_conteiner').outerHeight(true));
});
```

но результат ноль.

Дайте какой нибудь совет.

Comment: live устарело и уже не работает в новых версиях (с 1.9 кажется) используйте 'on'

Comment: погодите, у вас через ajax добавляется с id ? там не несколько таких блоков  в результате ?

Comment: да, div с id добавляется при клике с помощью jquery, затем загружаю из БД еще элементы

Answer (score 3):

Событие `scroll` не получится повесить на динамический элемент через метод `live()` и ему подобные.

Я посоветую так:

```
$('#block').on('mouseenter', '.element', function() {
    if($(this).data('scroll') == undefined) {
        $(this).data('scroll', true);

        $(this).scroll(function(){
            //...
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: нравится мне ваш код, но мне не помогает

Comment: @bemulima код полностью рабочий http://jsfiddle.net/q7dxu/

Comment: ну да, классно, у меня даже самый простой не работает

$('#fade').on('scroll', function(){
  alert('ok');
});

Comment: @bemulima если у вас окно не содержит скролла, то и скрипт не будет работать.

Comment: есть у меня сколл

Comment: @bemulima тогда сравнивайте рабочий код, который я кинул, и ваш код и ищите различия. Кстати, версия jQuery какая у вас?

Comment: Версия  v1.8. Да конечно, сравниваю. )